# My model always give empty even I have data in database Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

UPDATE
I just found the problem here, it is typo at $instID = $request->insititution;
It should be $instID = $request->institution;
Thanks for all your helps..

UPDATE

I trying to insert to CRConfigDetail Model / table, but first I need to get my CRConfigID from CRConfig Model / Table with specific rules. So I can get the CRConfigID and put it to CRConfigDetail column.

But every time I trying to retrieve, it always give empty data even I already have data at my database. In other Controller I can retrieve data with similar rules.

Am I do something wrong with logic? Because I don't see any errors.

Here is my HTML / form:

```
<form action="doInsertSCC" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="scheduleDetailForm">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="institution">Institution</label>
                    <select name="institution" class="form-control" id="institution">
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="acadCareer">Academic Career</label>
                    <select name="acadCareer" class="form-control" id="acadCareer">
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="period">Period</label>
                    <select name="period" class="form-control" id="period">
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="department">Department</label>
                    <select name="department" class="form-control" id="department">
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fos">Field of Study</label>
                    <select name="fos" class="form-control" id="fos">
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="scc">Lecturer's ID - Name</label>
                    <select name="scc" class="form-control" id="scc">
                    </select>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Assign SCC</button>
                <div id="search" class="btn btn-default">Search</div>
            </form>
```

Here is my Route to access my Controller

```
Route::post('/doInsertSCC', "ScheduleController@insertSCC");
```

And here is my ScheduleController

```
public function insertSCC(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'scc' => 'required'
        ]);

        $instID = $request->insititution;
        $acadID = $request->acadCareer;
        $termID = $request->period;
        $depID = $request->department;
        $rule = ['institutionID' => $instID, 'acadCareerID' => $acadID, 'termID' => $termID, 'departmentID' => $depID];
        $crConfig = CRConfig::where($rule)->first();

        if( !empty($crConfig) ){
            foreach ($crConfig as $cr) {
                $crConfigID = $cr->CRConfigID;
            }
            $schedule = new CRConfigDetail;
            $schedule->status = 'Pending';
            $schedule->numRevision = 0;
            $schedule->FOSID = $request->fos;
            $schedule->SCC = $request->scc;
            $schedule->CRConfigID = $crConfigID;
            $schedule->save();
            return redirect("AssignSCC")->with('status', 'Add SCC success!');
        }else{
            return redirect("AssignSCC")->with('status', 'Add schedule first!');
        }


    }
```

I already check my rules data are match with my CRConfig table's data (using console.log()

Everytime I submit this form, I will do the "else" and redirect with "Add schedule first!" message.

Comment: What does `dd($crConfig, $rule);` output? Add it above the not empty check.

Comment: @Robert I think institute give null, i got this error explanation when I want to access $crConfig: at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()', 'E:\xampp\htdocs\CourseReviewAndPeerReview\app\Http\Controllers\ScheduleController.php', '83', array('request' => object(Request), 'instID' => null, 'acadID' => '2', 'termID' => '2', 'depID' => '4', 'rule' => array('institutionID' => null, 'acadCareerID' => '2', 'termID' => '2', 'departmentID' => '4'), 'crConfig' => null)) in ScheduleController.php line 83

Comment: Yes, you do a `->first()` which will return a single `CRConfig` model or null. On line 83 you try to loop through the model, which you can not do. Hence the error. Btw, if it now fails on the foreach, that means that `$crConfig` is not empty?

Comment: @Robert aw I just found the problem here, it is typo at $instID = $request->insititution; It should be $instID = $request->institution;

Comment: that's 1 :), but the foreach will still fail though...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it does accept an array, but the array should be formatted as such..

```
$rule = [
    ['institutionID', '=', $instID],
    ['acadCareerID', '=', $acadID],
    ['termID', '=', $termID],
    ['departmentID', '=', $depID]
];
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses

Comment: There's no need for that, it defaults to the `=` operator when omitted.

Answer (score -2):

use the below one

```
$crConfig = CRConfig::where('institutionID' , $instID)
                      ->where('acadCareerID' , $acadID)
                      ->where('termID', $termID)
                      ->where('departmentID', $depID)
                      ->first();
```

instead of

```
 $rule = ['institutionID' => $instID, 'acadCareerID' => $acadID, 'termID' => $termID, 'departmentID' => $depID];
 $crConfig = CRConfig::where($rule)->first();
```

You can check the query built at the backend by getting the query log, for this you have to enable the query log before the query gets built and get the query log after the query gets built both query log methods belongs to DB facade

```
\DB::enableQueryLog();
\DB::getQueryLog();
```

Comment: Please let me know What is the error in this , some one down voted my answer

Comment: You are mistaking that the `where()` method does not accept an array. I have posted an answer with more detail.

Comment: `where()` does allow arrays

Comment: Thanks @SaeedPrez , I'm unaware of that

Comment: Thanks @Robert, I'm unaware of it

Comment: You are trying to pass an array without the []  bracket. What you have there will throw an error.

Comment: @oseintow Im trying to use multiple `where()` methods instead of using multi dimensional array,

Comment: then it should be `->where("institutionID", instID)` not  `->where("institutionID", => instID)`

Comment: Yeah @Robert my bad luck, I just copied from the question, I changed now, just now i noticed